# SimpleHTTPServer: other devices can't connect to the server

Tags: python, simplehttpserver

Lately I've been playing with Python to discover its potential and I've just stumbled upon SimpleHTTPServer.

I'm on Windows 10.

I run:

```
python -m SimpleHTTPServer
```

the output is:

```
Serving HTTP on 0.0.0.0 port 8000 ...
```

I've opened the browser both on smartphone and tablet, but none of them can connect to the server when I type "http://127.0.0.1:8000".

(Translating from italian, maybe is not the exact translation)

iPad: "Safari can't open the page because the server has stopped responding"

Android: "WebPage does not respond. the webpage may be temporarily not available or it could have been moved to another address"

Why does it not work? How do I fix this?

Comment: You need to know the IP of your physical server. Open powershell, and type in ipconfig. You need the "Ethernet adapter Local Area Connection"'s IPv4 Address

Comment: For example, it will likely be 192.168.1.195 something like this.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

127.0.0.1 is always the IP address of the local system (its associated hostname is "localhost").  In other words, if you type 127.0.0.1:8000 on your tablet or Android device, the browser on that device will try to connect to a server running on the same device, listening on port 8000.  You'll need to find out the IP address of the computer you're running Python on, and type that instead.  You can use the ifconfig command on Unix, or ipconfig on Windows.

Answer (score 5):

Maybe your firewall is blocking access to python based server

Try this:

- Open windows firewall
- click on "allow an app or feature..." on the left side of the opened window
- search for python in the list and check both the boxes private and public

It should work now

Comment: This could also be an issue, but it probably isn't. The problem is that the OP is trying to use the loopback address (`127.0.0.1`, aka `0.0.0.0`, aka `localhost`) from another device.

Comment: This worked for me. I had already allowed python to communicate through private networks, turns out it needs o be able to communicate on public networks as well.

Comment: Same for me @theEpsilon

Comment: This didn't work for me. Python is added to firewall exceptions, Android still cannot connect.